# run R code from Java Servlet

Tags: java, r, tomcat, servlets, renjin

I am trying to run some **R code from a Java Servlet** running in Eclipse as IDE on TomCat 7.0.

The **END goal** is to create a website running on **TOMCAT** or **JETTY** to show **Graphs + Data** made with existing R code that the R function returns as Base 64 code combined with the results of some existing Java and Python functions handling and creating advanced Excel files for instance.

*(I am not going to use R Shiny Server for a lot of reasons so i want to run R / Python from Java)*

To get a basic setup i created a Dynamic Web project with a simple servlet and a test.java file that can run R code.

test.java:

```
public class test {
      public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
          System.out.println(DoR.collectR());
      }
}
```

DoR.java:

```
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptException;

public class DoR {

  public static Object collectR() {
    ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("Renjin");
    if(engine == null) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Renjin Script Engine not found on the classpath.");
    }
    Object catchR = "XX";
    try {
        catchR = engine.eval("df <- data.frame(x=1:10, y=(1:10)+rnorm(n=10));"
                + "print(df);"
                + "print(lm(y ~ x, df))");
    } catch (ScriptException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return catchR;
   }
}
```

StartTestServlet.java:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/StartTestServlet")
public class StartTestServlet extends HttpServlet {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  public StartTestServlet() {
    super();
  }

  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    //response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath()).append((CharSequence) DoR.collectR());
    response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
  }

  protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    doGet(request, response);
  }
}
```

I have the libraries installed:

```
renjin-script-engine-0.7.0-RC2.jar
renjin-studio-0.8.1915-jar-with-dependencies.jar
slf4j-api-1.7.19.jar
slf4j-simple-1.7.19.jar
```

> If i run the test.java as a Java Application it works fine.
>
> If i run the servlet on the TomCat 7.0 server it works fine (without the .append((CharSequence) DoR.collectR())  )
>
> If i run the code with .append((CharSequence) DoR.collectR()) I get the exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Renjin Script Engine not found on the classpath.
    ......DoR.collectR(DoR.java:16)
    ......StartTestServlet.doGet(StartTestServlet.java:19)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
```

DoR.java:16 is the line with:

```
try {
```

StartTestServlet.doGet(StartTestServlet.java:19) is the line with:

```
response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath()).append((CharSequence) DoR.collectR());
```

> I have been trying all kinds of things to get this working in Eclipse Version: Mars.1 Release (4.5.1) And downloaded the Example files from Renjin / searching internet and so on but with no luck uptill now to get the R code running from within the Servlet.
>
> **Am i overlooking something simple or do i need to do it completely different ?**

Comment: How are you organizing your project's dependencies? Maven? Ivy? Gradle? Or are you doing it manually through the IDE?

Comment: @akbertram I use Maven. But the jar files are not in the Maven Repo so i have to put a different location for getting the jar files in my pom.xml. I did that and it could be that my firewall blocks this so the jar files are not downloaded by Maven. In this example i manage the jar files by hand, having Maven do this would be much better though =^)

Comment: Checkout http://renjin.org/downloads.html: You just need to add a <repository> section to your pom.xml with our repository address.

Comment: @akbertram that is exactly what i did. Could there be a firewall issue on my side that blocks a download from a different location than MAVEN itself ? (could you upvote my question so it gets more meaning for others too)

Comment: @akbertram I tried again -> See Maven Build message: [WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.renjin:renjin-script-engine/maven-metadata.xml from/to bedatadriven (https://nexus.bedatadriven.com/content/groups/public/): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target What could this be ?

Comment: Sounds like an issue making the https connection. Can you open an issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/bedatadriven/renjin/issues) with details on your java + os versions? Also, try navigating to https://nexus.bedatadriven.com with your webbrowser to see if the certificate is accepted- you might have a misbehaving proxy server?

Comment: @akbertram No problems opening nexus.bedatadriven.com but i get a warning/error on the https: This page is insecure (broken HTTPS). SHA-1 Certificate
The certificate for this site expires in 2017 or later, and the certificate chain contains a certificate signed using SHA-1. But the certificate seems OK. I will open an issue on Github and provide all info. I guess we do not have to use Stackoverflow for this till solved. =^J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the (newly added) [eclipse-dynamic-web-project](https://github.com/bedatadriven/renjin-examples/tree/master/eclipse-dynamic-web-project) in [Renjin Examples](https://github.com/bedatadriven/renjin-examples). To summarize the README:

1. Download the standalone renjin-script-engine-0.8.1931-jar-with-dependencies.jar from the [Renjin Downloads Page](http://www.renjin.org/downloads). You seem to be combining an old version of renjin-script-engine with the GUI jar.
2. Copy this JAR to WebContent/WEB-INF/lib so that it will be deployed along with your application.

Also look at your "DoR" method: you are calling `print()` which sends its output to standard output and returns `NULL`. On a webserver, this may get sent to the logs, but certainly will not end up in the response to the client.

If you want to send the results of the `lm()` function to the client,
you can serialize it using rjson::toJSON(), for example.

Comment: a great many thanks for creating this simple example that works =^) By the way a great many thanks for all the work you put into having this running and accessable to us all ! If you want i will share a more complex Java / R / Renjin program with a webpage showing a Base 64 image from ggplot later.

Comment: By the way, to prevent a json file to be saved / opend i changed the servlet a bit to:   //response.setContentType("application/json");//   //response.getOutputStream().print(result.getElementAsString(0));//                                    response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath()).append(" result: ").append(result.getElementAsString(0)); So it will show in the browser instead of in a file =^)